# Stop curl dropping the port number

Tags: php, image, curl, port

When I curl the following

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, "8081");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.0.14:8081/comingEpisodes/" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pass");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$curl_response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $curl_response;
?>
```

The page is returned however the images aren't. I located the problem. 192.168.0.14 is my local host. I am calling a page from an app the runs off port 8081. Curl seems to drop the port and change 192.168.0.14 to locahost and therefore the images are no longer linked to the right place. How do I make sure that the port remains so the images remain. Thanks

EDIT: I think the /comingEpisodes after the port is also part of the problem..

Comment: What images? I don't understand where you are fetching images

Comment: http://192.168.0.14:8081/comingEpisodes/ is a site that has images on it. The page loads but none of the pictures do because the urls have changed to localhost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're building a 100% proxy, you're dumping the contents of the cURL pull in to a browser. The results now refer from the page that the cURL results are dumped to, not from the originating cURL request.

Basically, if you visit http://localhost and the above code resides in the `index.php`, that page is requesting the :8081/comingEpisodes contents and dumping it within the *context* of the originating http://locahost. The browser is now basing all the found content from http://localhost and not as if it were from the curl request.

You *could* replace all the content links within the document before it's output to some "proxy.php?retrieve=old_url" and then make all those now call through the same cURL context, but that's the basis of a web proxy.

```
End-User               Intermediary              End-Website
(http://localhost)     (localhost/index.php)     (http://192.168.0.14:8081/comingEpisodes/)
------------------     ---------------------     ------------------------------------------
Initial visit--------->
                       cURL Request------------->
                                                 Page Content (html basically)
                       Echoed back to user<------
Content<---------------
Finds <img> etc.------>
                       /comingEpisodes/img1.jpg  // 404 error, it's actually on :8081
                                                 // that localhost has no idea about
                                                 // because it's being hidden using cURL
```

---

### VERY SIMPLE DEMO

```
<?php
  //
  // Very Dummied-down proxy
  //

  // Either get the url of the content they need, or use the default "page root"
  // when none is supplied. This is not robust at all, as this really only handles
  // relative urls (e.g. src="images/foo.jpg", something like src="http://foo.com/"
  // would become src="index.php?proxy=http://foo.com/" which makes the below turn
  // into "http://www.google.com/http://foo.com/")
  $_target = 'http://www.google.com/' . (isset($_GET['proxy']) ? $_GET['proxy'] : '');

  // Build the cURL request to get the page contents
  $cURL = curl_init($_target);
  try
  {
    // setup cURL to your liking
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // execute the request
    $page = curl_exec($cURL);

    // Forward along the content type (so images, files, etc all are understood correctly)
    $contentType = curl_getinfo($cURL, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
    header('Content-Type: ' . $contentType);

    // close curl, we're done.
    curl_close($cURL);

    // test against the content type. If it HTML then we need to re-parse
    // the page to add our proxy intercept in the URL so the visitor keeps using
    // our cURL request above for EVEYRTHING it needs from this site.
    if (strstr($contentType,'text/html') !== false)
    {
      //
      // It's html, replace all the references to content using URLs
      //

      // First, load our DOM parser
      $html = new DOMDocument();
      $html->formatOutput = true;
      @$html->loadHTML($page); // was getting parse errors, added @ for demo purposes.

      // simple demo, look for image references and change them
      foreach ($html->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img)
      {
        // take a typical image:
        //   <img src="logo.jpg" />
        // and make it go through the proxy (so it uses cURL again:
        //   <img src="index.php?proxy=logo.jpg" />
        $img->setAttribute('src', sprintf('%s?proxy=%s', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], urlencode($img->getAttribute('src'))));
      }

      // finally dump it to client with the urls changed
      echo $html->saveHTML();
    }
    else
    {
      // Not HTML, just dump it.
      echo $page;
    }
  }
  // just in case, probably want to do something with this.
  catch (Exception $ex)
  {
  }
```

Comment: If that's the case then when you curl a page say www.xyz.co.za why do all the pictures work if they changing to be relative to local host?

Comment: @Michael: Quick solution: do a `str_replace('</head>','<base href="http://192.168.0.14:8081/comingEpisodes/" /></head>',$curl_response);` before you echo it, then the browser will know where to look.

Comment: @Michael: to answer the immediate question, they're probably absolute addresses, not relative ones. the difference of `<img src="http://..." />` instead of `<img src="images/01.jpg" />` (which the browser will translate to `http://locahost/images/01.jpg` instead of the (desired) `http://192.168.0.14:8081/comingEpisodes/images/01.jpg`.)

Comment: @Brad: The problem with what you are suggesting is that it then makes another call to the server to fetch the images and the server is authenticated so it asks for the authentication again with a pop up. Can I somehow include the authentication in what you've suggested?

Comment: @Michael: Yes, you have to intercept _every_ call for content and apply your cURL method to it. Basically, initial call gets the page content. You then parse the content for any `href="..."`, `src="..."`, etc. and rewrite it to be (e.g.) `href="index.php?proxy=[original_link]"`.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but its over my head implementation wise. Would it be possible if you could write it out for me?

Comment: @Michael: The only real concept you need to know is that if you need to do your own connection handling, they all need to go through your PHP script. If you don't modify the links, resource targets, etc. the browser will try to retrieve them based on the page _its_ visiting, now where you've _actually_ retrieved them from. If you have any questions on my code, feel free to leave me a comment and I'll do my best to explain. That, however, should be a working demo. I would just note (after it's rendered) the `src` of the google image, and the `href` of the (for instance) links below search box.

Comment: For // setup cURL to your liking, do I need to curl_init(); again? and do I need CURLOPT_URL

Comment: @Michael: All your `curl_setopt` against the `$cURL` resource. And no, the construct of `curl_init` takes care of the url portion (with port) cURL presumably does something similar to [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and grabs as much info from the initial URL as possible.

Comment: It seems to be removing the images completely.. Like there used to be a table with images and when I failed earlier it has the placeholder with an x but now it doesn't have anything and the table is squashed.. Any ideas?

Comment: @Michael: Is it in the source code, or are they exempt all together? Remove the `@` on the `->loadHTML` call and make sure there are no syntax errors.

Comment: My bad! Didn't have a doc header in index.php

Comment: The url it needs to be is 

    http://192.168.0.14:8081/showPoster/?show=73388&which=poster

But its giving

    http://localhost/sickbeard_public/test.php?proxy=%2FshowPoster%2F%3Fshow%3D73388%26which%3Dposter

Which when I paste into the url bar gives me 

Unexpected query string parameters: which, show

Comment: @Brad Thanks for the help. This is getting to complicated. I think I'm gonna call it in. Thanks again

Comment: @Michael: Don't forget to `urlencode` the old url, so the `?`, `&` and `=` turn in to `%3F`, `%26` and `%3D`, respectively.

Comment: Too complicated. I'm cancelling this project its far to major for my knowledge level. Thanks again